# Encontrar ponto de lentidão no código .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, profiling

Preciso analisar um código que está demorando muito para executar, o código do método é extenso e faz várias chamadas para outros métodos, estive *debugando* para tentar identificar o ponto de lentidão, mas assim é muito difícil.

O Visual Studio possui alguma ferramenta que me ajuda nisso, para encontrar este ponto de lentidão?

Comment: O código é para uma aplicação web? Usa algum banco de dados?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você precisa de um [*profiler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). É a única ferramenta que dá para fazer isso do jeito certo.

O Visual Studio tem algo sim. Há [documentação oficial com vários detalhes sobre isso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/performance-tools-on-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012-applications?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Outras ferramentas disponíveis:

- [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).
- [ANTS](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).
- [JustTrace](https://docs.telerik.com/help/justtrace/introduction.html).
- [.NET Memory Profiler](https://memprofiler.com/).
- [SlimTune](https://code.google.com/p/slimtune/).
- [AQTime](https://smartbear.com/product/aqtime-pro/overview/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).