# Qual número máximo de itens que eu posso por dentro de uma List<T> no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, lista, objetos

Estou com diversas dúvidas de performance na minha aplicação. Qual o número máximo de itens que eu posso por dentro da minha `List<T>` e qual o "aceitável" dentro das boas práticas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009217/whats-the-max-items-in-a-listt

Comment: O limite tá na resposta do bigown. Agora, quanto a boas práticas: em geral quando se deseja melhorar performance o primeiro ponto a atacar é a complexidade dos algoritmos que você usa, não o tamanho das suas estruturas. Se o problema for algoritmo inadequado, aí sim você pode pensar em trocar a estrutura para poder usar outro algoritmo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Já que o [tipo do índice de acesso ao objeto do `List` é um `int`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,174) ([.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,143)) o limite teórico é 2 elevado a 31 ou 2.147.483.648.

Mas isso é mais complicado do que parece. Em geral cada objeto pode ter só 2GB de tamanho total alocado. Então a quantidade de itens que realmente pode ter depende do tipo `T`. Quanto maior ele for, menos itens pode alocar. Lembrando que se `T` é um [tipo por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) seu tamanho é sempre 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura.

Tem mais um detalhe. Em 64 bits é possível ligar a capacidade de aumentar o tamanho do objeto com a diretiva do *framework* [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://leran.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (disponível no 4.5 pra frente, e claro, no Core), aí em tese é possível trabalhar com todos os itens que o índice suporta. Só acho que será prático com objetos pequenos ou referência, e de preferência se tiver muita memória RAM.

Se precisar de mais itens que 2 bilhões, precisa de uma estrutura diferente, pode ser até usado o `List` como referência e mudar o índice para um `long` que fica virtualmente impossível estourar.

Lembre-se que qualquer coisa que faça a memória virtual agir para ficar trocando páginas da memória RAM para armazenamento secundário como HDD ou SSD pode tornar a aplicação em tragédia de performance. E como esse negócio de boas práticas é conversa mole, não tem como saber quando passou do limite assim. Tem que medir, tem que analisar, simular, tem que especificar onde sua aplicação pode rodar bem e deixar a pessoa aceitar a degradação se rodar com menos RAM do que você especificou.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: você sabe alguma ferramenta ou comando para eu saber quanto de memória(RAM) X objeto está utilizando?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti não é algo tão simples, em código só dá para saber aproximado (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199618/101). Tem ferramentas de perfilamento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108239/101.