# Quais ferramentas para otimizar um código C#?

Tags: c#, otimização

Ferramentas otimizadores de código visam, por exemplo:

**- Remoção de código morto:** remove qualquer código de classe, atributo ou método morto, que não é referenciado e utilizado no projeto.

**- Reescrever e reduzir funções:** renomeia o que for possível para aumentar ainda mais a performance de uso de memória pela APP (rótulos menores).

**- Aplicar o chamado Method inlined:** colocar constantes e métodos em linha de código.

Baseado nisso, podemos notar que o objetivo principal de um **otimizador de código** é diminuir o número de métodos invocados, e também de variáveis e constantes a serem acessadas em memória, consequentemente melhorando o desempenho do processamento da aplicação. 
Podemos notar também que o **otimizador de código** não necessariamente se preocupará com a legibilidade do código, sendo importante ter uma cópia do original não otimizado para futuras consultas, conforme já é comum de ser feito quando ofuscamos um determinado código. Muitas das ações feitas por um **otimizador de código** passam despercebidas aos olhos dos programadores, pois o objetivo do profissional é manter um código legível aplicando conceitos que podem ser ineficientes quanto ao processamento.

- Compiladores podem realizar um leve trabalho de otimização do código, assim como alguns ofuscadores também o fazem, na linguagem Java temos o [Proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) e o [Dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard), que otimizam e ofuscam o código.
- Programas dedicados a otimização podem fazer o serviço de maneira mais eficiente.

**Otimizadores de código** são comuns em linguagens interpretadas, devido ao fato de não haver um compilador disponível para tais linguagens. Para o JavaScript temos o [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), que é capaz de reduzir o peso dos códigos, bem como o consumo de recursos na máquina cliente, apenas reescrevendo atributos e métodos, logicamente sem alterar o resultado final das classes.

Após este breve resumo, gostaria de saber se alguém conhece ferramentas voltadas ao C# semelhantes ao que citei aqui.

Comment: Otimizar tipo como?

Comment: Se você der uma olhada na página do Closure Compiler entenderá melhor o que quero dizer com "otimização". Mas, basicamente esses otimizadores deixam o código mais leve e eficiente a nível de processamento.

Comment: O compilador do C# já faz esse processo de otimização. Sobre melhorar o código legível, como citaram o ReSharper ajuda bastante, só toma cuidado que nenhuma ferramenta fará milagre, no fim das contas essas ferramentas apenas aconselham.

Comment: @GabrielColetta sempre cabe questionar a mudança e entender o porque esta sendo feita

Comment: Você quer um aconselhador de melhorias no fonte ou quer algo que efetivamente reduza coisas desnecessárias no alvo?

Comment: Eu sou meio bolado com micro-otimizações. Normalmente sou mais a favor de usar um _profiler_ e detectar os pontos reais de gargalo, para então propor uma solução adequada seja de _peephole_ ou uma abordagem totalmente diferenciada

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado O que é um profiler?

Comment: Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108244/64969). Creio que nela você encontre a referência mais adequada para o assunto

Comment: Fechei a pergunta porque ele pede certas coisas, inclusive dando exemplos de ferramentas semelhantes e a resposta dada fala de um produto que não oferece essas essas coisas e o AP diz que era exatamente o que ele queria. Então ele não sabe o que quer, não descreveu direito o problema e uma resposta que não bate com a pergunta será enganoso para muita gente que ler aqui.

Comment: @Maniero Reescrevi a pergunta, espero que agora todos consigam entendê-la.

Comment: @DanOver não acho que tenha salvação mais. Ela continua pedindo uma coisa e a resposta entrega outra.

Comment: @Maniero Estranho, eu li e consegui entender que ele queria e logo pensei no Resharp. Me parece estranho, minha resposta ser errada com tantos upvotes. Pior ainda, o próprio dono achou a resposta correta, não me parece justo como alguns não conseguem entender a questão ser fechada.

Comment: @LuizSantos extamente por isso ela está fechada. Ela fala uma coisa e as pessoas entendem outra. É a definição de não clara. Os votos são porque as pessoas estão entendendo errado e porque as pessoas gostam do Reshsarper. Tem votos por outro motivo, mas isso será tratado de outra forma.

Comment: @Maniero Me parece subjetivo, porém ok. Tudo que você esta em dizendo parece ser a sua visão da situação. Mas, quem sou eu para contestar.

Comment: @Maniero Porém, sendo bem sincero, está situação é bem desmotivadora e soa mandatória

Comment: @DanOver é importante que as perguntas levem a criar respostas objetivas e sobre assuntos específicos. Se a pergunta fizer com que cada respondedor possa escolher do que falar de maneira desfocada esta pergunta e resposta(s)  fica uma salada e muito difícil de manter com o tempo. Quanto mais especifica a pergunta for melhor.

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi o que a pergunta pede exatamente. Se é otimização, se é melhoria, e em qual dos sentidos da pergunta (a resposta me confunde mais ainda, apesar de eu não estar considerando para o fechamento). Não sei se fica ampla ainda, depois de esclarecida.

Comment: @LuizSantos , aqui me parece que o ReSharper faz um trabalho semelhante ao que o CheckStyle faz para Java. E o CheckStyle não é visto como otimizador, na verdade ele não otimiza nada. O ProGuard, por outro lado, altera o código compilado para, por exemplo, minificar strings e tornar o carregamento de classes internas mais rápido. Então, eu concordo com o que o Maniero falou. Sobre pontuação positiva, pode ser porque sua resposta contribui para a comunidade de algum jeito, mas não necessariamente que contribua resolvendo o problema direto da pergunta

Comment: Entendi! Galera, o problema é com a palavra otimizar, otimizar não significa apenas "deixar mais rápido" escrever com menos palavras a mesma função é uma "otimização", não existe nenhuma ligação da palavra "otimização" com velocidade, por mais que o ReSharp traga velocidade.  Otimizar: criar condições mais favoráveis para; tirar o melhor partido possível de.

Comment: Bom, vamos lá.. Após pesquisar encontrei um software chamado Eazfuscator.NET (Gapotchenko), este software atende bem aos requisitos destacados na pergunta. Resumidamente ele é um substituto do ProGuarg (muito utilizado por quem programa em Java), porém o Eazfuscator.NET é voltado a plataforma .NET. Assim como o ProGuard, ele age ofuscando e realizando tarefas de otimização automática do código. Há outras features. Na página do software (https://goo.gl/YzT4xt), é possível verificar como é realizada a otimização automática do códido. É programas como este que o autor da pergunta esta procurando.

Answer (score 8):

Para melhoria de código C#, o meu favorito é o [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Ele faz diversas melhorias no código como:

- analisar a qualidade do código;
- eliminar erros e cheques de código;
- alterar com segurança a base do código;
- percorrer instantaneamente toda a solução;
- desfrute de ajudantes de edição de código;
- cumprir os padrões de codificação.

Na minha vivência posso atestar que ele já me livrou de:

- `if` que nunca entrariam;
- código redundante;
- referências desnecessárias;
- elegância e legibilidade do código;
- renomear atributos e classes com maior segurança.

Super aconselho.

Comment: E la vem o downvote sem aconselhamento de melhoria.

Comment: É exatamente ferramentas como esta que procuro. Vou procurar conhecê-lo.

Comment: @DanOver a instalação é fácil e o uso mais ainda. Bom proveito

Comment: @LuizSantos excelente resposta, Obrigado por esse conhecimento! +1

Comment: Eu gosto do Resharper mas não o utilizo, o Visual Studio já tem um desempenho ruim, com o Resharper ele fica ainda pior, e o próprio visual Studio tem muita das funções que o Resharper tem.

Comment: Obrigado galera, fico feliz pelo retorno :) @DanOver se puder marcar como certa clicando no ✓  fico grato.

Comment: @Aesir eu considero que todos os dois valem o peso, mas o resharp ja esta disponivel para o visualstudio code, que é mais leve.

Comment: Reconheço o mérito do Resharper, CodeFx, entre outros, porém creio que é **obrigação** do desenvolvedor fazer tudo pedido acima. Focamos em escrever mal e incorretamente depois usamos uma ferramenta para 'corrigir' erros gerados, às vezes até por imperícia técnica. 
Se você é esforçado e gosta de boas práticas, seu código já será produzido sem a necessidade de uma ferramenta assim...

Comment: Então Daniel, a ideia no caso do resharp é que você vá aprendendo de acordo com as correções, vá de educando. Não é para ser uma moleta

Comment: Sou fã do Resharper também.. 
eu particularmente uso 
- Resharper
- CodeMaid (Ajuda bastante a "limpar código")
- OzCode (muito bom pra debugar, ver listas no Linq, fera mesmo vale a  pena)

Comment: @DanOver Dado que a pergunta foi reaberta, há algo que eu possa fazer para melhora-la?

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro Acho que ele é semelhante ao corretor do word, te ajuda a melhorar e ver onde erra e evita erros de vacilo. Talvez o único ponto negativo seja a lentidão.

Comment: @LuizSantos realmente é um pouco mais pesado mas compensa..,.. mas se você for a fundo ele tem muito recurso bacana, por exemplo a parte de Unit Tests ajuda demais.. facilita.. os atalhos (tipo Ctrl+T) ficou bom demais... o "using" sem precisar "Ctrl + ponto"... foda o refactor que ele faz pra ajudar criar interface das classes.. , tem bastante coisa mesmo , depende muito do seu estilo de código! :)

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro Eu sou todo a favor do resharp

Comment: @LuizSantos interpretei mal sua resposta, até editei a minha,  se voce curte ele, experimenta o OzCode.. é pago também.. pra fazer debug.. é TOP... vou escrever um artigo no medium sobre ele.

Comment: experimentarei.